# Slow performance for Azure Table Storage queries

Tags: c#, azure, task-parallel-library, azure-table-storage

I'm running a series of well-structured queries against Azure Table Storage that should, so far as I can tell, be returning sub-second. Indeed, if I run them manually (say, from the Azure tools inside Visual Studio), they are indeed returning immediately. But when I'm running them in production, they are sometimes taking upwards of 20-30 seconds to return.

Here's the C# code that I'm calling ATS with:

```
public async Task<IList<T>> FindAsync(string filter, int maxRecords = int.MaxValue, IList<string> columns = null)
{
    var returnList = new List<T>();
    try
    {
        Interlocked.Increment(ref _outstandingRequests);
        var query = new TableQuery<T>().Where(filter);
        if (columns != null && columns.Any())
        {
            query = query.Select(columns);
        }
        TableQuerySegment<T> querySegment = null;
        var sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        while (returnList.Count < maxRecords && (querySegment == null || querySegment.ContinuationToken != null))
        {
            try
            {
                await 3.RetriesAsync(async x =>
                {
                    querySegment = await
                        Table.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(query,
                            querySegment != null ? querySegment.ContinuationToken : null);
                });
                returnList.AddRange(querySegment);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.Error("Error executing ATS query; table:{0}; filter:{1}; error:{2}",
                    typeof(T).GetFriendlyTypeName(), filter, ex.CompleteMessage());
                throw;
            }
        }
        sw.Stop();
        if (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds > 10000)
        {
            var stat = new RepoOperationStats(filter, sw, returnList.Count, _outstandingRequests);
            _logger.Warn("Long-running {0} query: secs:{1:0.0}, rc:{2}, or:{3}, fi:{4}",
                typeof(T).GetFriendlyTypeName(), stat.Milliseconds / 1000d, stat.ResultCount, stat.OutstandingRequests, stat.Filter);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        Interlocked.Decrement(ref _outstandingRequests);
    }
    return returnList;
}
```

And here's an example of an entity stored in the table:

[image]

All fairly straightforward. But in my logs, I'm seeing repeated errors like this:

> Long-running AtsOrganizationEventSummaryByCookie query: 
>   secs:33.3, 
>   rc:0, 
>   or:94, 
>   fi:(PartitionKey eq '4306.www-detail-mercury-mars-skywatching-tips.html-get') and ((RowKey ge '2015.02.05.00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000') and (RowKey le '2015.02.07.00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'))

In other words, it's taking 33 seconds to return zero rows. Note that it's hitting exactly one partition, and it should be able to do a simple seek on the row index within that partition. (And indeed, the same query returns immediately in other contexts.)

Is there some sort of throttling mechanism that I'm running into? I should note that I *am* calling these queries in parallel, so that at any given point in time, anywhere from a dozen to upwards of 100 queries could be outstanding. But it seems like both (a) my client, and (b) ATS should be able to handle that level of load.

Any suggestions for how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: what does the azure stoage log say - thats usually pretty revealing. Normal cause of slowness is cross partition search and / or table scan (ie linear search of table)

Comment: I've looked through the storage logs, and haven't seen anything terribly interesting. The latency figures seem to be within 20-30 milliseconds, and nothing else looks at all out of whack. I agree that partition and/or table scans are typical sources of performance issues, but in this case, I've broken up the queries so that they're quite definitely hitting just one partition per query, and with a reasonable rowkey constraint.

Comment: When you say latency figures are 20-30 ms - which latency?  End to end, or server?  If E2E latency is very low then the problem isn't in the call to storage, it is somewhere else in the code.  Have you added trace statements in the while loop to make sure your code is being called with the parameters you expect and the number of times you expect?  Also consider enabling client side tracing the storage client library - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn782839.aspx.

Comment: I was referring to the `AverageE2ELatency` and `AverageServerLatency` columns in the `$MetricsHourPrimaryTransactions` table. They're both around 30-40 ms. For what it's worth, in investigating it further, it turns out that only about .1% of my queries are running this slow. I still don't know what was causing that, but I've addressed it so far with better caching, which means fewer queries against ATS, which means fewer slow queries.

Answer (score 0):

What is your filter? From the log you have, looks like you are doing a scan operation with

`(RowKey ge '2015.02.05.00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000') and (RowKey le '2015.02.07.00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000')`

Although `RowKey` is indexed, when you filter by a range of rowkeys with comparison like `ge` or `le`, it performs a scan instead, which can be very slow depending on the size of your table.

You can try loading the whole partition `4306.www-detail-mercury-mars-skywatching-tips.html-get` in memory and do the filtering to see if it's faster.

Btw, from your entity data structure, looks like you are trying log event for accessing a web page. If you are, you may want to check out Application Insights. It's more suitable for telemetry logging.